# how to retrive data from JSON in javascript @

Tags: javascript, json

```
let data = {
  
  "@type": "Movie",
  "url": "/title/tt0443272/",
  "name": "Lincoln",
  "image": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTQzNzczMDUyNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjM2ODEzOA@@._V1_.jpg",
  "description": "As the American Civil War continues to rage, America&apos;s president struggles with continuing carnage on the battlefield as he fights with many inside his own cabinet on the decision to emancipate the slaves.",
   
 
 
  
  "duration": "PT2H30M"
}


console.log(data.@type)
```

i have large json data from scrping but i don't know how to get value of data whose
key is starting from "@"

how can i get value of @type

when i am use this method i got error :-

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: try with `data["@type"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables in JavaScript can only start either a letter, dollar sign, or underscore.

When using an invalid variable name you cannot use dot notation and must use bracket notation

Invalid

```
data.@type
```

Correct

```
data['@type']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do `console.log(data['@type'])`

```js
let data = {
  "@type": "Movie",
  "url": "/title/tt0443272/",
  "name": "Lincoln",
  "image": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTQzNzczMDUyNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjM2ODEzOA@@._V1_.jpg",
  "description": "As the American Civil War continues to rage, America&apos;s president struggles with continuing carnage on the battlefield as he fights with many inside his own cabinet on the decision to emancipate the slaves.",
  "duration": "PT2H30M"
}


console.log(data['@type'])
```

Comment: that's working from me TNX : )

Answer (score 0):

You can access variable properties using the [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) as well, like if its a key -> value:

```js
let data = {

    "@type": "Movie",
    "url": "/title/tt0443272/",
    "name": "Lincoln",
    "image": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTQzNzczMDUyNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjM2ODEzOA@@._V1_.jpg",
    "description": "As the American Civil War continues to rage, America&apos;s president struggles with continuing carnage on the battlefield as he fights with many inside his own cabinet on the decision to emancipate the slaves.",

    "duration": "PT2H30M"
}


console.log(data["@type"])
```